# Paypal DirectPayment Error - JAVA NVP

Tags: java, paypal

I am testing with Paypal Sandbox ,
I want to get Credit Card Payment on my site from PayPal ,

**So according to documentation ,  for all business sandbox accounts created in my developer's account , i have already enabled paypal's billing agreement and now my account type is business pro,**

see attached image,
[image]

after that when i try to get credit card's payment on my web site, PayPal gives following error,

```
Paypal Transaction Error Occurred :
Error Code : 10501
Error Short Message : Invalid Configuration
Error Description : This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.
Error Severity Code : Error
```

I am using following method

DirectPayment

and the final String i am generating

```
METHOD=DoDirectPayment&VERSION=93&TENDER=C&TRXTYPE=S&ACCT=4646409327660838&EXPDATE=012017&CVV2=111&ACCTTYPE=Visa&AMT=48.0&CURRENCYCODE=USD&FIRSTNAME=null&LASTNAME=null&STREET=ff 20&CITY=Vadodara&STATE=&ZIP=&COUNTRY=null&INVNUM=44fcf284-e83c-4f50-8248-f5b0ed6f28fd&ORDERDESC=null&ITEMAMT=48.0&VERBOSITY=HIGH&Email=test@test.com&Ponum=44fcf284-e83c-4f50-8248-f5b0ed6f28fd&PhoneNum=6365414705IPADDRESS=localhost&BUTTONSOURCE=PP-ECWizard
```

> i have removed some confidential detail from here.

any help ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to pay whith credit card but your account in Paypal is not enabled for it. Please check first Funding tab in your sandbox account.

I think Credit card type need to containt Visa. Please check eligibility too. I have also Business Pro account but I don't enable direct credit card option. Please check your.

[image]

If you already enable direct credit card please check also which credits card excepted in your country. The specification say:

> Website Payments Pro is available in the United States, Canada, and
>   the United Kingdom. Minor regional differences include transaction
>   limits, the kinds of credit cards accepted, and address information.

Note:

> For direct payment only, American Express restricts direct card
>   acceptance merchants in certain business categories. Merchants are
>   required to accept the American Express Card Acceptance agreement in
>   order to process American Express cards directly.

[This specification](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_wpp_integrationguide.pdf) created at December 2012. May be its old. Please check new if it exists.

Comment: @Mihir So, Did you enabled live credentials also?

Answer (score 0):

I am not hoping this strange behavior by PayPal, i contacted support and after 20 days no reply from them,

according to my experience when the PayPal redirection method works and Payment by Credit Card (Direct Payment) doe not work

**The cause is , PayFlow is not enabled on Your SandBox Account on which you are receiving payment. i already did it , and generally ita takes 2 mins after updating , but it seems in my case it did take longer and after 20 days i can receive payment on same account Via Direct Payment.**